# Python - can't find sub modules after importing the parent module

Tags: python

I have a question about importing python modules.

For example, with pandas, I can do:

```
import pandas as pd
```

Then I can access all the functions and sub-modules from the pd object directly.

However, when I do the same with sklearn,

```
import sklearn as sk
```

I can't access the sub-modules from the sk object. There's only a few methods and properties available from this object.

for example I want to use the sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer() function but I can't do something like:

```
sk.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer()
```

I have to explicitly import the text module first and then use its functions:

```
import sklearn.feature_extraction.text as sk_text
sk_text.CountVectorizer()
```

Can someone please explain what's going on and how I can fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some parts of modules are explicitly separated in their construction, so that the user must import them explicitly. This is useful to prevent cluttering the namespace and reducing memory requirements when libraries (such as Scikit-learn) hold so many sub-libraries.

Here are [a collection of import gotchas](http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/import_traps.html) and the part that is [relevant for you](http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/import_traps.html#the-submodules-are-added-to-the-package-namespace-trap).